# Memory Leak - ActiveSupport - Dependencies

Tags: ruby-on-rails, memory-leaks, ruby-on-rails-5

I recently caught some memory leaking in my application.

Taking a normal heap dump and analyzing shows:

```
object count (670282)
==============================
  95930  activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293
  92143  activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql/database_statements.rb:111
  49151  activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/core_ext/marshal.rb:4
  13439  activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/attribute.rb:5
  13423  activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/result.rb:123
  13422

High Ref Counts
==============================

  283240  activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/result.rb:123
  201375  activesupport-5.0.2/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:293
  67110  activerecord-5.0.2/lib/active_record/attribute_set/builder.rb:19
```

Notice highest object count for `active_support` dependencies and their high ref count. The method its referring to is:

```
def require(file)
  result = false
  load_dependency(file) { result = super }
  result
end
```

https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/5-0-stable/activesupport/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb#L293

Any one have any idea what this method is doing and why retaining so much memory?

Answer (score 0):

That line (specifically, the call to `super`) receives attribution for all objects created during the process of performing every `require`.

It is pointed to because it's the last line of Ruby code executed, but the objects it's being blamed for aren't related to Active Support at all: they're the result of parsing all the other Ruby scripts you're loading, and of initializing any C extensions.